# Twitter API v2 - Free Version - Getting Follower Numbers - 2023

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Does anyone know if it is still possible to collect the number of followers for a given Twitter account using the free version of the Twitter v2 API (after Feb 9th, 2023)?

I tried getting access to the API using the following code, but got the following error:

```
import tweepy
import requests

# Replace with your own keys and tokens

API_KEY = 'persnal key'
API_SECRET_KEY = 'persnal key'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'persnal key'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'persnal key'

# Authenticate using your keys and tokens

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Create the API object

api = tweepy.API(auth)

def get_followers_count(screen_name):
    user = api.get_user(screen_name=screen_name)  # Update this line
    return user.followers_count

# Replace 'screen_name' with the desired Twitter account's screen name

screen_name = 'account_x'
followers_count = get_followers_count(screen_name)

print(f'The number of followers for {screen_name} is: {followers_count}')
```

Error:
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

Comment: The error message literally answers your question.

Comment: Now the error message is outdated.  There is no Elevated access form on Twitter's developer portal, and you only need the free tier to access the authenticated user's data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using twitter api v1 while you have access only to API v2

In api v2 free tier you can access only to post tweets and `GET /2/users/me`, where you can get user details including follower count

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user

Answer (score 0):

With the v2 API you can only access data for yourself or the authenticated user.

With 1.1 API you can access public data, including followers for any account like this:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=alfrednerstu
```

Based on the code and error message it looks like you're using the 1.1 API already but that your Developer account is on an old Essential plan. You need to upgrade to the new Free plan.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @PatrickHennessey X (Twitter) has since my answer closed the 1.1 API and only v2 API is available now.

Answer (score -1):

The Twitter Api is still working in 2023, but sometimes the api credentials in the app get suspended , so you just need to create new app in the twitter developper platform;

I found this interesting 2023 tutorial of how to extract twitter data in python , and it still working, here is the videos links

- Extract Twitter Data from Twitter API in Python Using Tweepy [2023 Tutorial]
  https://youtu.be/EIuvnhlmn24
- Get Twitter API in 2023 for FREE ( Still Working !)
  https://youtu.be/PkacG2UYMps

Comment: This is not working, to get the follower count you need tu upgrade your tier (so not free)